# Insert into table based on value

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

Below is the table `UPI_ATTRIBUTE_TABLE` and column names are `UPI_ATTRIBUTE_ID`,`USER_PROFILING_ID`, `USER_PROFILING_NAME`,`SITE_INCLUSION`,`SITE_EXCLUSION` under which the values are there.

**Problem Statement:-**

I need to insert values in `SITE_INCLUSION` and `SITE_EXCLUSION` column for `CAR_EXPLICIT (USER_PROFILING_NAME)` and `CAR_IMPLICIT (USER_PROFILING_NAME)` values. But Currently `SITE_INCLUSION` and `SITE_EXCLUSION` is empty corresponding to `CAR_EXPLICIT` and `CAR_IMPLICIT`. I need to add "0" in front of the SITE_INCLUSION for now. And datatype for SITE_INCLUSION and SITE_EXCLUSION is varchar2(200). After adding "0" infront of CAR_EXPLICIT and CAR_IMPLICT in SITE_INCLUSION column, it should look like below table. And currently SITE_INCLUSION and SITE_EXCLUSION is empty(null) infront of CAR_EXPLICIT and CAR_IMPLICIT.

And also if I need to update the same value from "0" to "0;100", then how can I do that.

```
**UPI_ATTRIBUTE_TABLE**

UPI_ATTRIBUTE_ID       USER_PROFILING_ID    USER_PROFILING_NAME          SITE_INCLUSION     SITE_EXCLUSION
5000000000              1                   LAST_QUERIES_USED
5000000001              11                  LAST_CATEGORIES_ACCESSED
5000000002              4                   LAST_PRODUCTS_VIEWED
----                    ----                ----           
----                    ----                ----
----                    ----                ----
----                   ----                 ----
5000000094             156                  CAR_EXPLICIT                    0
5000000095             155                  CAR_IMPLICIT                    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE UPI_ATTRIBUTE_TABLE 
   SET SITE_INCLUSION = '0' + USER_PROFILING_NAME
 WHERE USER_PROFILING_NAME IN ('CAR_EXPLICIT','CAR_IMPLICIT') ;
```

?

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain me what is the use of having `USER_PROFILING_NAME` in this line `SET SITE_INCLUSION = '0' + USER_PROFILING_NAME`. As i am new to this syntax.

Comment: Yes that's how I was interpreting your comment, "After adding '0' infront of CAR_EXPLICIT and CAR_IMPLICT in SITE_INCLUSION column," but if you just wanted to put a zero by itself you would remove the "+ USER_PROFILING_NAME" bit from the syntax. As-is, the result would be "0CAR_EXPLICIT" or "0_CAR_IMPLICIT" in those columns.

Comment: Yup, it makes sense now. I only need `0`. Thanks.

Comment: But suppose if I need to set it back again to empty, then what should I do? As previously it is empty. And after making changes now it has '0'. So how I can make that empty.?